# jquery/javascript errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

does anyone know why the following script is not working.

I'm trying to see if the cookie is set and when it it's i wan't to see if the value is 1 or 0 if the value is 1 i wan't to move my div#content with an offset, but when it's is 0 i want to move it with the same offset, but in the opposit direction

```
$(function() {
    var loc = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );

    if("index.php" == loc[3] && (document.cookie('subMenu') === null || document.cookie('subMenu') == 0)) {
        document.cookie("subMenu", 1);
        animatethis("#content", 1500, "+=50px");
    }
    else 
    {
        if(!"index.php" == loc[3] && (document.cookie('subMenu') == 1)
        {
            document.cookie("subMenu", 0);
            animatethis("#content", 1500, "-=50px");
        }
    }
});

function animatethis(targetElement, speed, offset) {
    var x = $('#menuwrapper').height();

    $(targetElement).animate({ marginTop: "+=50"},
    {
        duration: speed,
    });
};
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: I don't get any error, but the animation doesn't work, while when i get the cookie checking and set out of my code it does work

Comment: What was happening on executing the code? You haven't used "offset" varibale in "animatethis" function.

Comment: corrected the offset in the animatethis, when i have executed the code whitout the cookie, my content div has moved to the bottom. but with the cookie nothing happend

Comment: @Abdelkarim Abdoe, The way of cookie read and write aren't correct. are you sure about cookie set?

Comment: no i am not sure about it, how are they set en read? can you give me an example

Comment: Cookie set/get is most common thing. You can get lot of code snippet in online. Anyway refer this http://www.perlscriptsjavascripts.com/js/cookies.html

Answer (score 0):

You just don't use your `offset` variable here :

```
$(targetElement).animate({ marginTop: "+=50"},
{
     duration: speed,

});
```

Try this :

```
$(targetElement).animate({ marginTop: offset},
{
    duration: speed,

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error. Missed end of first bracket in following line:

```
//It would be
if(!"index.php" == loc[3] && (document.cookie('subMenu') == 1))

//In place of 
if(!"index.php" == loc[3] && (document.cookie('subMenu') == 1)
```